# Fixate document length to n pages

Tags: spacing, typography

I often find myself squeezing documents to meet ensure the final document is below some set length. I often do this by cutting whitespace, enlarging pages by a  line height, etc., and of course by trying to write succinctly.

Out of curiosity, is there some way to force LaTeX to compile a document to a fixed number of pages?

I understand that this will most likely make the document look absolutely horrible, but I hope it will give an idea of how many darlings to kill before the document fits the length requirement.

Comment: While I might find an answer to your question interesting, I often find that the easiest way to get rid of pages is first to take a look at every line that shorter than one third of the page and remove a couple of useless words from their paragraph. This pretty much removes the extra line. Another good option is typesetting in `twocolumn` if you can afford it with your style requirements. 2 pages in `twocolumn` typically makes 2,5 in `onecolumn` for me.

Comment: You are right: "this will most likely make the document look absolutely horrible"

Comment: You could always reduce the font size.

Comment: This is why word counts make so much more sense than page counts...

Answer (score 9):

This document is forced to 5 pages (don't try this at home:-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcount\maxpage
\maxpage=5


\AtBeginDocument{\setbox0\vbox\bgroup}
\AtEndDocument{\egroup
\dimen0=\dimexpr\ht0 / \maxpage\relax
\count0=1
\loop
\setbox2\vsplit0 to \dimen0
\vbox to \textheight{\unvbox2\vss}%
\pagebreak
\ifnum\count0<\maxpage
\repeat
\vbox to \textheight{\unvbox0\vss}%
}


\def\a{One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thriteen fourteen. }
\def\b{Red green blue yellow black white brown. }
\def\c{\stepcounter{enumi}\Roman{enumi}: \a\a\a\a\b\b\a\a\b\a}
\def\d{\c\b\b\a\a\c\b\c\b\b\b\c\c\c\b}

\begin{document}


\section{Aaaa}

\d\par\d\d

\section{BBB}

\c\c\a\par\c

\section{CCC}

\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\par
\a\a\c\a\a\a\a\a\a\par
\a\a\a\a\c\a\a\a\a\par


\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed it is! I followed your advise and tried at work. I added more text - then the bottom margin is broken rather than text squeezed. Is it possible to put higher priority to not breaking margins than to respecting whitespace?

Comment: @Rasmus  you could try it without the two instances of `\vss` or with replacing `\vss` by `\vfil` either of those things makes it more likely that existing space on the page is shrunk as much as possible. If you find a variant that works for you comment here and I'll update answer